# Control Characters in Resource files C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unicode

I want to add `Left-To-Right` control character in `resource.resx` file in `Visual Studio`. I searched over internet and came across a tutorial called [Another Way to Escape Sequences in .NET Resource Files](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/34769) which say inorder to insert a unicode character in resource file, press the Alt key and type decimal equivalent of unicode from NumPad. But using the way described, when I type 8206(decimal equivalent of \u200e, it inserts ♫ and the same character is being displayed in the output as well. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways, I can think of:

- Copy the character from the character map
- Right-click the text field and select »Insert Unicode control character« and then »LRM Left to right control character«
- Use `&#x200e;` in the source code.

Comment: I added another option after actually trying it out.