# How to avoid C# adding an escape character when obtaining string value from asp.net resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to pass a Unicode character corresponding to fontawesome icons to the text property of an asp.net web forms button control from the code behind. It works fine when I do the following:

```
button1.Text = "\xf044";
```

However I have to get it from a resource file to conform with the company requirement. When I set the resx file with name/value as "Edit" and "\xf044". The problem is that when I set the Text property equal to this value from resx, it is set automatically as follows.

```
button1.Text = "\\xf044";
```

Is there anyway to avoid this? I tried something as follows

```
button1.Text = myResx.Edit.Substring(1);
```

Now the button instead of displaying the corresponding font icon, simply displays "\xf044".

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the correct string is in the resource file?

Comment: Yes, the resource file has the value of "\xf044" without quotes.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17402383/563088 it might be a duplicate