# Can't insert unicode symbol in C# resource file

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF app and need to display the "white star" (u+2606) character in a label.  Of course if I set the string in code with "\u2606" it works fine.  However, I can't figure out how to put this into the resource file.  When I type ALT+2606 it inputs a period instead of the start.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you see a period?  In the resource file or the label? It's possible that the font displaying the period does not support that character.

Comment: If you're trying to put it directly in the XML you might try `&#x2606;`

Comment: The period shows in the resource file.  I did try the &#x2606 but it displayed exactly that, as if it was a literal string.

Comment: If you write `&#x2606;` into the Resource File Editor, it generates `<value>&amp;#x2606;</value>` in Resources.resx. Replace that by `<value>&#x2606;</value>`.

Comment: Ok, so i did get this to work.  I must have missed the semicolon or something before.

Answer (score 3):

From this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402383/control-characters-in-resource-files-c-sharp) - try inserting from the Character Map.

To launch the Character map from the command prompt, type `charmap`.

Select Segoe-UI-Symbol and type 2606 in the Unicode box.  Click on the star, then Click the Select button and then the Copy button will put it into your clipboard.

[image]

Comment: That still inserts a period into the XML.

Comment: When I paste into the resource editor using these instructions, I see:  ☆ in the XML.  Do you see the star in the resource editor after you paste after following these instructions?

Comment: i think it's because of the specific font you're using vs. mine.

Comment: yea @user1278533 that white star only exists on certain fonts.  Here was the list of fonts that support the white star that I found:  https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2606/fontsupport.htm